# Enable logging for JDK class programmatically

Tags: java, logging

Ok, the case is simple. I need to be able to enable/disable logging for a JDK class (HttpURLConnection) programmatically.

```
public class HttpLoggingTest {

    /**
      Just a dummy to get some action from HttpURLConnection
    */
    private static void getSomething(String urlStr) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        System.out.println("----- " + urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : conn.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());
        }
        conn.disconnect();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        // HERE : Enable JDK logging for class
        // sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
        getSomething("http://www.goodle.com");

        // HERE: Disable JDK logging for class
        // sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
        getSomething("http://www.microsoft.com");           
    }        
}
```

In other words: before the first URL call the logging must be enabled and then disabled before the next call.

That is the challenge !
I'm unable to figure out how to do it.

Must work with Java 7.

#### Note:

I can do it by using configuration file, `logging.properties` :

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL
```

but I want to have a programmatic solution.

#### UPDATE

Here's code that works in Java 6 but not in Java 7:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;    

public class HttpLoggingTest {

    /**
      Just a dummy to get some action from HttpURLConnection
    */
    private static void getSomething(String urlStr) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        System.out.println("----- " + urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : conn.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());
        }
        conn.disconnect();            
    }

    private static void enableConsoleHandler() {
        //get the top Logger
        Logger topLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("");

        // Handler for console (reuse it if it already exists)
        Handler consoleHandler = null;
        //see if there is already a console handler
        for (Handler handler : topLogger.getHandlers()) {
            if (handler instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
                //found the console handler
                consoleHandler = handler;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (consoleHandler == null) {
            //there was no console handler found, create a new one
            consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
            topLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
        }
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        enableConsoleHandler();

        final Logger httpLogger = Logger.getLogger("sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection");


        // Enable JDK logging for class
        //sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
        httpLogger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINE);
        getSomething("http://www.goodle.com");

        // Disable JDK logging for class
        // sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
        httpLogger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.INFO);
        getSomething("http://www.microsoft.com");           
    }        
}
```

#### UPDATE2

In order to make sure that a solution *only* enables output from our target class (and not all sorts of other JDK internal classes) I've created this minimal JAXB example. Here JAXB is simply an example of 'something else', it could have been any other part of the JDK that also use PlatformLogger.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 * Minimal dummy JAXB example. Only purpose is to provoke
 * some JAXB action. Non-prod quality!
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
public class Celebrity {

    @XmlElement
    public String getFirstName() {
        return "Marilyn";
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getLastName() {
        return "Monroe";
    }

    public void printXML() {
        JAXBContext context;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Celebrity.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.marshal(this, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiate an instance of the `Celebrity` class and call `printXML()`. Put that into `getSomething()` method. This must not generate JAXB internal logging output ... or else you've enabled logging for more than you thought.

Comment: Note: the example can be copy/pasted and executes as-is.

Comment: What are you trying to log? Only the headers?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No the display of the headers is just to provoke some action in the example. I don't decide what gets logged. That's up to the `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` class ... and I'm happy with that. But how do I enable it programmatically ?

Comment: That code doesn't compile for me in Java 7. Entry is unresolvable. Supposed to be Map.Entry I assume.

Comment: @mttdbrd. Must be your imports that are wrong. I've included them now in the example above.

Comment: Sorry my solution didn't work. This just makes sense the more I think about it. Logging is built in to the JDK; it needs to work reliably and consistently. Set the level to SEVERE if you want nothing logged but as you're probably aware that will set the logging level for the JVM. That means you're going to affect whatever else is running not just in your JVM instance but in all programs that will thereafter use that JVM.

Comment: Also, wait, is this simpler than we thought? There is a Level.OFF which turns off logging. Setting OFF should be proxied through to the PlatformLogger. I just don't have time to test this right now though. Off to work. I'll check back in later.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled over [PlatformLoggingMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/PlatformLoggingMXBean.html) the other day. I'll need to try something like:

```
PlatformLoggingMXBean platformLoggingMXBean = 
    ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(PlatformLoggingMXBean.class);
platformLoggingMXBean.setLoggerLevel(
    "sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection", "FINE");
```

and see it it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
java.util.logging.Logger logger = 
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(
            "sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection");
logger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINE);
```

Comment: Nope. Sorry mate. If only it was that simple. See updated question above.

Comment: Mate, gave you a downvote first but removed it again because you are trying to be helpful (appreciated!) and of course this is the right answer ... if it wasn't because this is Java 7 and the class in question is internal JDK. :-(

Comment: this doesn't work on Java 8 either. On Java 8 this worked

`sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger
            .getLogger("sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection")
            .setLevel(PlatformLogger.Level.ALL);`

so I reckon this'll work on Java 7 too