# How do I fix whatever is causing this to flood my logcat: I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Tags: android, logcat

I'm writing an Android app that access the internet. It runs without error, but ever since I upgraded my device (Samsung Galaxy S5) to Android 5.0.1 my logcat is flooded with the following messages when my phone runs the app:

```
05-20 16:05:35.514  23322-23440/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:35.514  23322-23440/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
05-20 16:05:35.514  23322-23440/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Thread-23345-153023149: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
05-20 16:05:35.514  23322-23440/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:35.564  23322-23440/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-20 16:05:36.184  23322-23440/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:37.784  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:37.884  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:38.034  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:38.164  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:38.404  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:38.544  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:38.774  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:38.864  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:39.084  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:39.204  23322-23634/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
...
05-20 16:05:46.334  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:46.364  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:46.404  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:46.454  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:46.514  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:46.554  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:46.604  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:47.964  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.644  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.674  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.694  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.704  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-20 16:05:48.754  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.804  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.844  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.874  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.914  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.944  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:48.994  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.564  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.604  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.654  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.714  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.744  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.774  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.824  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.834  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.864  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.904  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.944  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:50.984  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.014  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.044  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.094  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.124  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.144  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.204  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.224  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.254  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.304  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.424  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.504  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.554  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.594  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.624  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.654  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.714  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.744  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:51.774  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:53.134  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:53.204  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:53.324  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:53.384  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:53.414  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:53.444  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:54.684  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:54.724  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-20 16:05:54.744  23322-24029/scave.dvend I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

That is an *extremely* small sample of what my logcat looks like. What does this even mean? Is there some way to set "isSBSettingEnabled" to true just to make it shut up?

Comment: I think this is Samsung-specific.

Comment: and it's not possible to avoid this log to fill our logging files or consoles? no ideas?

Comment: I have the same problems, during using google maps utility .... any way to fix it?

Comment: What network operation is your app performing at this point of time? Is your application firing too many network requests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the regex filter to hide the log message flooding your log:

```
^((?!isSBSettingEnabled).)*$
```

You can also hide more than one offending log by using `|`. For example

```
^((?!isSBSettingEnabled|OtherLog|OtherLog2|Annoying Messages).)*$
```

Comment: @anthonymonori, yes it does. It filters to show any log message not containing the string "isSBSettingEnabled." Is your Regex box checked? Otherwise the filter doesn't work.

Comment: Suggesting to fix the OPs problem by hiding the logs from the output/LogCat window is everything but not a reasonable answer. The answer should focus on helping the OP to fix the issue at hand (of why it is printed out in the first place - focus on what it says in the log) instead of hiding

Comment: OP is asking how they can remove the message from their logs. This does just that. The other answer does the exact same thing just on the programmatic level and requires that line of code on every activity generating the log entry. This eliminates having to apply the duck-tape to code, so to speak.

Comment: Marking as the answer since this is the most non-intrusive solution I've found for this.

Comment: For me, this is filtering out the whole output (android studio 3.1.1)

Comment: @captainserious while I can see your point, this is Android world.. you can often pick only between duct tape and chewing gum solutions, truly fixing the source of the problem is often impossible.

Comment: I agree this helps to hide the issue, not solve it. I down voted for that reason. I'm in need of finding a reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably using a `HttpUrlConnection` or a `HttpsUrlConnection`. Maybe you can find out which class is logging by calling `getClass()` on the corresponding connection and turn it off with the `Logger.getLogger("...").setLevel(Level.OFF);`

See also [Enable logging for JDK class programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031110/enable-logging-for-jdk-class-programmatically)

Comment: final Logger httpLogger = Logger.getLogger(HttpURLConnection.class.getName ()); httpLogger.setLevel (Level.OFF); but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `HttpLoggingInterceptor` on the application that runs on a Samsung device, just set the loglevel to the body, it will fix everything. Something like this should work fine:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

Answer (score 0):

**A better solution is offered in Android 7.0 through network security configuration file.**
*How to use it?*
1. Add a network security config file under res/xml.
2. Add a domain config and set cleartextTrafficPermitted to “true”.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_domain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

3. Add your network security config to your Android manifest file under application.

   ```
   <application
       android:name=".MyApplication"
       android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
   ```

Comment: Did not work for me - but I'm using an IP address instead for a domain name.

Answer (score -3):

**Solution:**

Add in your `application` tag:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

As follows:

```
<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ....>
```