# Turn off console logging for URLConnection

Tags: java, logging, urlconnection

I'm opening a connection, grabbing URLs from the site I'm connecting to, then creating more connections based on the URLs received from the first one.

Each time I open a connection, this message prints to the console:

```
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

I looked through [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) and found setDoOutput, which after reading into it, is not the behavior I'm looking for (disabling HTTPLog).

Is this possible through `URLConnection`? If not, what's an alternative?

Comment: It sure is possible, but `URLConnection` is an abstract class and a quick look into the JDK revealed no such log statement. So it could be that we're talking about some 3rd party lib here. Also: Do you know which logger the statement uses? Java Logging API, Log4j, Logback, etc. This is important because you (usually) have to disable the log level using the specific logging framework its being written by.

Comment: @Brian There are no third party libraries involved. I will see if I can reproduce the error with a public site so I can post an MCVE. I'm actually using a subset of the JDK (for Android), but I doubt the implementation is much different. I'm pretty sure it's the Java Logging API, seeing how the JDK is the only dependency in my project, unless it were by some odd chance using a third party logging library

Comment: So it's an Android implementation, didn't know that. Searching the internet revealed that this might be a Samsung issue. You don't happen to use Samsung as your target? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360823/how-do-i-fix-whatever-is-causing-this-to-flood-my-logcat-i-system-out-httplog