# I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false?

Tags: android, picasso

I am getting this when using a recycle view along with Picasso library to fetch images from sound cloud. The problem is that the app freezes for few seconds sometimes. Then, I get a message of skipping frames and doing too much work on the main thread. I am using retrofit to perform the Http connection.

```
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
I/Choreographer: Skipped 102 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Comment: And `I/System.out` is simply an INFO message from `System.out.println`, not necessarily an error or anything to care about

Comment: Another possible duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360823/how-do-i-fix-whatever-is-causing-this-to-flood-my-logcat-i-system-out-httplog

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason for App freezing is because of the error " The application may be doing too much work on its main thread". The reason for this error is maybe you are trying to download images of a bigger size which is exceeding the app memory.Using large size images or resource files also causes this error. "isSBSettingEnabled false" is may be because of using HttpUrlConnection, this mainly occurs while using Samsung devices. Try using emulator.

Comment: Best answer so far. I have the same issue. The threads seem to get stuck when trying to download too many images using the "picasso" library.

Comment: I'm using J7 Prime and Samsung Tab 3 their API is level 23 and 19. In Tab 3 all is smooth. But in j7 prime which is Marshmallow. This error occurs.

Comment: same for me with SAMSUNG device

Comment: I am doing google sign in flutter. So why I am getting these warning or log because as I am not downloading any data from the internet. What is the reason can anybody tell? Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. also I am getting this. but my login is successfull

Comment: Same, Am using Samsung S8+

Comment: I'm recently having this issue. Is it like a Samsung thing or something?

Comment: Same problem on Samsung Galaxy S8.

Answer (score 5):

I may be too late but it can help someone.
I encountered this situation in two case. First situation I was trying to download something big and doing simultaneous download, I was not quite sure if it was a problem but I changed the mechanism for download and used okhttp.
Second time Yes it was also in downloading but this time it was a bad URL that I was using:
http://example.com/file to download.pdf (look here space was the problem). Formatting the URL was the only thing to fix it.

Comment: In addition You can rely on this library for download They did an amazing job the developer there
https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add this attribute to your  part in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

This could solve the problem on my app.

Answer (score 1):

Change the compile sdk version to 27, I also faced the same issue with my app, just replace the compilesdk version to 27,

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have a game that connects to socket.io and was having this issue, it wouldn't connect to the server, this solution worked for me, care to explain with details? It's weird because it started when I downloaded the latest android version

Answer (score 1):

I tried simply changing the target not even the compiledsdkVersion and it worked! :

targetSdkVersion 27

edit :

However to upload on google play your targetSdk version must not be lower than the compiledSdk

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there trying to debug this problem.

This occurs to me, whenever I try to access a null variable.

I am yet to learn the intricacies of null safety thoroughly. The code does not
through any error.

The execution just seems to freeze before the null variable
is encountered.

Spent quiet a number of days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score -1):

You should increase the request timeout, that's how:

**1)** Subclass a `Downloader` class

**2)** Preconfigure `OkHttpClient` with timeouts and pass it to `Picasso`

Answer (score -1):

this reason is you are targeting android 12
just add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
in the androidManifist.xml file

Answer (score -7):

add this in AndroidMainfest and try

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: If that was the case, the application would be crashing, not freezing