# How to change isSBSettingEnabled false to true?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

After I use device_info_plus package and try to get the device info then the app is not navigating. During google authentication I am trying to get the android id of the phone and store that in cloud firestore along with google id. I am trying to restrict the user from logging in from any other device from the same account.

```
D/InputTransport(10544): Input channel destroyed: 'a8ed6c ', fd=98
W/.medical_tayar(10544): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/System  (10544): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out(10544): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(10544): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/ViewRootImpl@7d3edce[MainActivity](10544): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7d3edce[MainActivity](10544): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/System.out(10544): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(10544): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(10544): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(10544): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(10544): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(10544): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

Code I have inserted is:

```
 GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
  ],
);
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async{
  try {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    if(googleSignInAccount!= null){
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await
      googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      //credential gives everything needed about user
      AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,

      );


      final UserCredential authResult = await
      auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      final User? user = authResult.user;
      var userData = {
        'name': googleSignInAccount.displayName,
        'provider': 'google',
        'photoUrl': googleSignInAccount.photoUrl,
        'email': googleSignInAccount.email,
        'android': androidInfo.model,
      };
      users.doc(user!.uid).get().then((doc) {

        if(doc.exists){
          //old user logged in
          doc.reference.update(userData);
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Collections.collection);
        }
        else{
          //new user logged in
          users.doc(user.uid).set(userData);
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Collections.collection);
        }
      }
      );

    }
  }
  catch(PlatformException){
    print(PlatformException);
  }
}
```

Anyone Please help?

Comment: What exactly is not working with the code? And what is it you expect the code to do but it is not doing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix whatever is causing this to flood my logcat: I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360823/how-do-i-fix-whatever-is-causing-this-to-flood-my-logcat-i-system-out-httplog)

Comment: It is not sending data to the cloud firestore database. But it was working fine before i the package device_info_plus to get the information of the device

Comment: Why do you think `isSBSettingEnabled` is related to your problem?  Why do you believe you need to set it to true?